# Contour detection on sketched lines

Tags: graphics, computer-vision

I have a set of curves as input, represented as a list op point coordinates.
I want to merge them into one, more or less beautiful, curve.
Any idea how to do that?

[image: Raw curves]

### [image: Output]

UPDATE:

It should work on a single curve like that:

[image: Simple Curve]

The most important aspect, to make the result curve nice, and supress the draw errors.

Comment: I realized, that it is too much to ask. Not easy to make an algorithm that can distinguish between intentional corners, and badly drawn curves. Updated the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have zero noise in your image, that is there is no salt-and-pepper artefacts just a somewhat curvy lines.  The easiest way to merge them if there are not that many gaps is to use blur or morphological expansion to connect parts together (both may distort a shape just a bit) and then use findContour().

[image]
[image]
[image]

If there are larger gaps you have to use convex Hull on convex parts and then on concave residuals. Snake or active contour algorithm is probably an overkill in this situation.

Comment: A minor problem with this solution, is that the merged has an offset to the original. The major one, is that the result carries all the noise from the badly drawn input. It should look like a b-spline.

Comment: You can always extract inner as well as outer contours and take their average. I showed only an outer contour. You can also smooth your curve now since you have it. I cannot do everything.